# Where is dist/out-tsc-e2e when running ng e2e?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I'm running `ng e2e`.

I'm expecting to see compiled javascript in `dist/out-tsc-e2e`; however, I'm not seeing this directory (`out-tsc-e2e`).

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

The reason I ask is because I'm confused about what is happening when I run `ng e2e`.

Is that when the typescript files in `e2e/` get compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to the way angular-cli scaffolds a project. I believe the reason for this is if you did run `tsc` in this directory, that the files would be transpiled to the `dist/` directory. This is great because the transpiled JavaScript files will not be committed since dist/ is part of the `.gitignore`.

The Protractor tests when you run `ng e2e` do not transpile the TypeScript because the `onPrepare` method uses `ts-node` to run the TypeScript without transpiling to JavaScript.